# Syntax error Mysql

Tags: mysql

No Idea why this is not working - could someone please help?

```
update c set c.images = ""
from j17_content c
inner join j17_jreviews_content rc on rc.contentid = c.id 
inner join j17_categories cat on cat.id = c.catid
where cat.path like "cakes%"
and c.created_by in (62,63,99)
and rc.email = 'email'
```

error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from j17_content c inner join j17_jreviews_content rc on rc.contentid = c.id in' at line 2

UPDATE:

Now trying

```
UPDATE j17_content c SET c.images=''
inner join j17_jreviews_content rc on rc.contentid = c.id 
inner join j17_categories cat on cat.id = c.catid
where cat.path like 'cakes%'
and c.created_by in (62,63,99)
and rc.email = 'email'
```

still getting

error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join j17_jreviews_content rc on rc.contentid = c.id inner join j17_catego' at line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this is not really the way you guys suggested - but I got a list of IDs and updated them using no joins with an in statement of all the IDs

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` doesn't take a `FROM`.

The syntax should be `UPDATE j17_content c SET c.images="" INNER JOIN ...`

Comment: thanks for the answer - now im getting #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join j17_jreviews_content rc on rc.contentid = c.id inner join j17_catego' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

This is essentailly your code.

Try it this way:

```
update j17_content c 
inner join j17_jreviews_content rc on rc.contentid = c.id  
inner join j17_categories cat on cat.id = c.catid 
where cat.path like 'cakes%'
and c.created_by in (62,63,99) 
and rc.email = 'email' 
set c.images = '';
```

This is an UPDATE JOIN

I have a refactored version of the query in mind

```
update  
(
    SELECT content_id id
    FROM j17_jreviews_content
    WHERE email = 'email'
) rc
inner join j17_content c USING (id)
inner join
(
    SELECT id catid
    FROM j17_categories
    WHERE created_by in (62,63,99)
    AND path like 'cakes%'
) cat USING (catid)
set c.images = '';
```

You will need indexes for the subqueries involved

```
ALTER TABLE j17_categories ADD INDEX created_by_path_id_ndx (created_by,path,id);
ALTER TABLE j17_jreviews_content ADD INDEX email_content_id_ndx (email,content_id);
```

Comment: there must be something wrong with my mysql server! #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where cat.path like "cakes%" and c.created_by in (62,63,99) and rc.email = 'email' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

replace your double quotes(") with single ones(')